# Can I use a rosnode to communicate with a server?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to GET and POST some data to and from the server. Can I simply create a C++ code that creates a node and uses < boost/asio.hpp> library to connect to the server, obtain the data, convert from JSON to ROS msg and publish that message to the topic? And vice verca (publishing the message to server using < boost/asio.hpp>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306221/can-i-use-a-rosnode-to-communicate-with-a-server?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-10-19**:
As has been said. This is definitely possible. A c++ ROS node is simpley an application which includes the ROS libraries. So you can do anything in it that any other application can do.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-19**:
Related: #q306127.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds perfectly possible. There are already similar packages, for example the [mqtt_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/mqtt_bridge) that converts between ROS and MQTT.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-10-19**:
Yes but it uses mqtt broker which is an extra step. I want a pure api thing. So what is the purpose of libraries like roslibjs if I can do it everything inside the node code?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-10-19**:
the mqtt_bridge was only an example in which ros-messages are streamed into the not-ROS-world